# Incorporate Open Source C++ Code Libraries into Xcode 5.1

Tags: c++, xcode, open-source

I am new to programming in Xcode and I want to be able to use open source code in my future c++ projects (e.g. machine learning/ computer vision libraries). Additionally, I never really understood the process involved in linking and using any c++ libraries besides the standard library, and I was hoping someone could outline the process or point me in the right direction.

I would really appreciate some help starting with the downloading of the 3rd party source code. I have been searching around finding bits and pieces of the process, but none of the posts seemed to be specifically directed to my problem, so please let me know if I have done something wrong already.

I began by downloading the dlib library. I located the source code with cmake, I clicked configure and generate without changing any options and this gave me an Xcode project. I then built the project for running and this produced the file libdlib.a in the associated debug folder. I then dragged the file into the link with binary libraries. My archive file is now located in the project, but I'm not sure what to do from here.

1. How can I get Xcode to recognize this with the include function?
   e.g. #include < dlib >     ,   #include < dlib/matrix.h > , using namespace dlib
2. What other steps do I need to take to be able use the functions/objects defined by the library?
3. Do I need to include any source code besides the archive file in my project?
4. Will this process roughly be the same for any library I download, or does it need to be specifically tailored to each?
5. Is there a specific location on the computer where I should put these libraries? or do I just need to identify their location in Xcode?
6. After following this process, will Xcode "know" all the associated functions from the library? 
     e.g. if I start typing, will it fill in the rest of the name, or notify you the necessary arguments for each function?

Thanks for the help,
Jake

Answer (score 1):

The C and C++ build process is as follows:

1. preprocessing
2. compilation
3. assembly
4. linking

The steps you need to configure in order to use a third party library are the preprocessing step, for the library headers, and the linking step, so that references to library entities in your program will be linked to the relevant code in the library binaries.

---

`#include` directives are handled by the preprocessor, which process a single .cpp file at a time and among other things replaces those `#include` directives with the contents of the named file. To do this it must know where to get the file from, which it gets from the "include search paths".

Some search paths are preconfigured for you, such as the ones for the standard library. For any other headers you will have to add the appropriate search path. On the command line this usually uses the `-I` flag with an argument.

```
clang -E -I /path/to/wherever/you/put/the/library/headers main.cpp
```

In your Xcode project's build settings you will find a place to add include search paths.

---

Just as you must link together the separate object files so that calling the function `foo()` in main.cpp will run your definition of `foo()` from foo.cpp, you have to link to whatever third party libraries you want to use. A .a file is a library archive file that is little more than a bundle of .o files. The linker knows how to handle this so you don't need to un-bundle anything, you simply need to tell the linker to link the .a file in your executable.

There's more than one way to do this, but the most common is to set the library search paths to include the directory where the .a is located, and to tell the linker to look for a library with a particular name. Setting the library search paths uses the -L flag, and as long as the .a file follows the usual naming convention (libXXX.a) then you tell the linker to search for and use the library with the flag -lXXX.

```
clang -L /path/to/libraries -ldlib main.o foo.o bar.o
```

You can also just pass the library like another object file:

```
clang main.o foo.o bar.o /path/to/libraries/libdlib.a
```

And again in your Xcode project settings there's an entry for library search paths. Adding the .a file to the "link with binary libraries" area should result in the -l flag being properly added, so you shouldn't have to add that separately.